# What does "1\/1." mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and I have something to match with (`/^1\/1. Guess a word from an anagram [RUBY]{4}$/`)

Please, what does "`1\/1`." mean in this expression. Can anyone explain what's going on for me.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: This isn't actually a question about Ruby. Many languages use regular expressions, with a common (or extremely similar) syntax.

Comment: This is well noted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a backslash in a regular expression *escapes* the next character, so that it's treated as an ordinary character rather than whatever its special meaning would be. For instance `a*` matches zero or more of the letter `a`, but `a\*` matches, literally, an `a` followed by a star. Since most regular expressions in Ruby are wrapped in the delimiter `/`, we can't directly put forward slashes in our regex. If we had written

```
/^1/1. Guess a word from an anagram [RUBY]{4}$/
```

Then the regex would be `/^1/` and the rest of the line would be a very confusing syntax error. This is for the same reasons that we can't put `"` characters directly inside of a `"`-delimited string.

So a backslash treats it as an actual slash in the expression rather than a delimiter.

```
/^1\/1. Guess a word from an anagram [RUBY]{4}$/
```

We're literally matches a `1` followed by a slash followed by a `1` at the start of the line.

Comment: Your explanation was so helpful. Thanks so much